# Should the bcrypt hash be stored in the main User's table or in its own table?

Tags: php, mysql, bcrypt

From what I've read, the hash generated by bcrypt should be stored as type `CHAR(60)`.

Now, should those bcrypt hashes be stored in the main `User` table together with the user's `UserID` and `Username`, or should it be stored in its own table with 2 columns `(UserID, BcryptHash)`?

Comment: Preference really I would say.

Comment: *Proper normalization* says that it should be stored in the `User` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to store it in the `User` table. It doesn't really matter. For simplicity I would store it in `User`.

Comment: @phpNoOb: Not sure why you're giving him a hard time, his answer is correct, as corroborated by Sammitch in the comments above.  It's short, but it's the answer I was looking for, and it's correct, so writing it as an answer will make it easier to find for those having the same question in the future.  Thanks joeframbach!

Answer (score 0):

By your preference I think, for 1st normal form is a repeat of item; about this concept you can use only a field, but (if i must to do that) I prefer 2 columns.
paladinux